# Fixed a typo that I thought should disable an entire route resource but only disables URIs with a wildcard

Tags: php, laravel

Simple blog crud app, adding tag functionality and all routes are working well so far. The index and create pages are rendering, new tags are storing fine, but when I try to hit the edit page (/admin/tag/1/edit) Laravel throws a

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

I check my route:list and it looks good, Firebug is just giving a basic 404 not found on GET app.dev/admin/tag/1/edit. Eventually I noticed a trailing slash on the tag route:

```
$router->group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    ], function () {
    resource('admin/post', 'PostController');
    resource('admin/tag/', 'TagController');
});
```

changed it to

```
    resource('admin/tag', 'TagController');
```

and now the edit pages render just fine.

Eventually I realized that this also happenes on any URI with a wildcard {$id} (destroy, edit, show, update). So my question is basically why. Why do the non wildcard URIs work just fine but not the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need use `prefix` in route group:

```
$router->group([
  'prefix' => 'admin',  // <= prefix
  'namespace' => 'Admin',
  'middleware' => 'auth',      
  ], function () {
  resource('post', 'PostController'); // <= changes , eq. admin/post
  resource('tag', 'TagController');  // <= changes , eq. admin/tag
});
```

About "trailing slash". I suppose, it related only with resource routing & your wrong using it route group. Before, look in docs about [actions handled by resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Then,if you look at `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php`, you can see line:

```
   protected $resourceDefaults = ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'];
```

Then look at method 'register':

```
    public function register($name, $controller, array $options = [])
{
    // If the resource name contains a slash, we will assume the developer wishes to
    // register these resource routes with a prefix so we will set that up out of
    // the box so they don't have to mess with it. Otherwise, we will continue.
    if (Str::contains($name, '/')) {
        $this->prefixedResource($name, $controller, $options);
        return;
    }

    // We need to extract the base resource from the resource name. Nested resources
    // are supported in the framework, but we need to know what name to use for a
    // place-holder on the route wildcards, which should be the base resources.
    $base = $this->getResourceWildcard(last(explode('.', $name)));

    $defaults = $this->resourceDefaults;

    foreach ($this->getResourceMethods($defaults, $options) as $m) {
        $this->{'addResource'.ucfirst($m)}($name, $base, $controller, $options);
    }
}
```

Your `admin/tag/` is going throgh this condition:

```
if (Str::contains($name, '/')) { /*...*/ }
```

I am not plunged deeper ( you can do it by yourself), but I assume that on 99% problem in `explode/implode` ( when "trailing slash" is exists - see definitions for *actions handled by resource controller*) => router can resolve action for create or index, but can`t resolve for edit,etc. ( we got 404 ).